# Stuck on a simple query - OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have a simple query to get, but I'm stuck and I really can't figure out how to do this.
More specifically:
The table `Allarmi` has a lot of entries, which i show all grouped by `Allarmi.IDComponente`

something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM ALLARMI AS ALLARMI
WHERE ID_CELLA = 1
GROUP BY ID_Componente
```

I only need to add to this table a `COUNT` column, something like

```
(SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM allarmi
WHERE isAttivo = 1
GROUP BY id_componente)
```

but I would like to show `COUNT` even when its `0` or `NULL`

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a table that contains all possible components?

Comment: Yes... Table "Componenti" which also contains columns ID_Componente and ID_Cella

Comment: What are you trying to count?

Comment: can you explain more what are the tables involve? the structure, maybe.

Comment: every alarm is connected to a component, which is identified by id_cella and id_componente. every componente can have multiple alarms. i want to count all the alarms that are connected to the single component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming table `Componenti` defines the components, and you want to get a count of records from `allarmi` for each component, what you actually want to do is select the component from `Componenti` and add a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) on `allarmi`

```
SELECT COMPONENTI.ID_Componente, COUNT(ALLARMI.ID_Componente)
FROM COMPONENTI
LEFT OUTER JOIN ALLARMI ON
   -- insert your join here!
   -- maybe COMPONENTI.ID_Componente= ALLARMI.ID_Componente?
   -- add any query for this table here as well.
   AND ALLARMI.ID_Cella = 1
GROUP BY COMPONENTI.ID_Componente
```

Comment: OMG i really knew it was so stupid, but i just couldn remember the syntax of JOIN and GROUP BY! I was close though... Thank you sir ;)

Comment: There's a little problem. If i count like that, i get the count of all the components with that ID, which is wrong, because i can have 2 components with same ID_Componente, but different ID_Cella, and they are different, so i need to count different alarms... I'm sorry if I still bother you... Do you have a solution?

Comment: YOu are counting on a specific ID_Cella?  And that field is in the ALLARMI table?  Add that in your left outer join.  See edit

Comment: I think i have finally found the right way to proceed and in the end I solved like this. Given that i wanted to count how many alarms where on for a single component, instead of COUNT, i used SUM (Allarmi.isAttivo) and i finally got it working

SELECT *, SUM(ALLARMI.ISATTIVO)
FROM ALLARMI
WHERE ID_CELLA = 1
GROUP BY ALLARMI.ID_COMPONENTE

Thanks all for your help